# void pointers in C++

Tags: c++

I saw this example on a website, and the websites mentions:-
"One of its uses (void pointers) may be to pass generic parameters to a function"

```
// increaser
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void increase (void* data, int psize)
{
  if ( psize == sizeof(char) )
  { char* pchar; pchar=(char*)data; ++(*pchar); }
  else if (psize == sizeof(int) )
  { int* pint; pint=(int*)data; ++(*pint); }
}

int main ()
{
  char a = 'x';
  int b = 1602;
  increase (&a,sizeof(a));
  increase (&b,sizeof(b));
  cout << a << ", " << b << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

wouldn't it be simpler to write code like the following?

```
void increaseChar (char* charData)
{
    ++(*charData);
}

void increaseInt (int* intData)
{
    ++(*intData);
}

int main ()
{
  char a = 'x';
  int b = 1602;
  increaseChar (&a);
  increaseInt (&b);
  cout << a << ", " << b << endl;
  string str;
  cin >> str;
  return 0;
}
```

It is less code, and really straightforward. And in the first code I had to send the size of the data type here I don't!

Comment: But now you have two functions instead of only one, which means you can't (for example) register `increase` as an event listener in some framework. You're correct that the example given isn't a realistic usage, and even in a more appropriate context, it's unusual to pass a data pointer *and* a size to a callback. The interface to `pthread_create` is a more plausible example, although in C++ you might prefer to use a more C++-ish API such as Boost.Thread.

Comment: The first is a common C idiom that *some* people think is also appropriate in C++. It generally isn't. Use inheritance, templates etc. instead whenever possible to preserve type safety.

Comment: @larsman I completely agree. This example is only good for C. Not for C++. I had mainly used `(void *)` when interfacing with C code, as an opaque pointer. And also with MS COM in C++. AFAIR ::QueryInterface() also uses a `void*&` as an output parameter.

Comment: And I have also used `(void*)` for implementing the PImpl idiom in C++... But these are exceptions to the rule of strong typing.

Comment: @Stephane Rolland: I'd never use `void*` for pimpl, always smart pointers.

Answer (score 14):

It would be best to make the function type safe and generic.  It would also be best to take the argument by reference instead of by pointer:

```
template <typename T>
void increment(T& data) {
    ++data;
}
```

`void*` should be avoided wherever possible in C++, because templates and inheritance provide type-safe alternatives.

Comment: Templates are the way to go. Type-safety enforced at compile-time. I'd just go one step further and pass data as `T&`. In most cases, you won't even have to write `increment<int>(i)`, as the compiler will usually deduce the type `T` automatically.

Comment: @Mephane, type inference should work here too, I guess? Using a pointer here's not *so* bad, as you see explicitly from function call that your parameter's going to be modified.

Comment: please pass that argument by reference.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is definitely preferable.  `void*` loses any pretense to type safety, your typesafe overloads are much better.  Good instincts.

To support more types generically in C++ you would define a class or function template, not use `void*`.  References would be preferable to pointers, but your code could be changed to this:

```
template <class T> T increase(T* value)
{
    return ++(*value);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int i(0);
    increase<int>(&i);

    char c(0);
    increase<char>(&c);

    return 0;
}
```

What's the website, as a matter of interest?

Comment: Well, lol, it`s the cplusplus website: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/

Comment: @w4j3d - thanks for the note, that's not great advice at http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/

Answer (score 0):

Your solution works only for int or char. Consider the situation you want to go through array of some custom type( struct, for example ). In your code you will need to add a method to do that, however in the example above no line of could should be added to get the work example.

Answer (score 0):

> "One of its uses (void pointers) may be to pass generic parameters to a function"

Not a good-style use, to be certain. Passing generic parameters to functions is done by:

**a)** templates (and possibly template specializations) which allows to write safe code,
**b)** OOP approaches.

I like your second `increaseInt` and `increaseChar` solution better. You can rewrite it as:

```
template<typename T>
void increase(T* pData)
{
    ++(*pData);
}
```

It will work for any type which supports `++` and be safe.

---

Sometimes you'd still need a void pointer as a "generic parameter" - for example when using the popular `pthread` library. When you spawn a thread, you may send it some arbitrary data (of any type you want), and it's done using - well - a `void*` pointer. The `pthread` library is in C not C++, which may be one of the reasons, but you might want to interface with it from C++ and this will indeed require you to use the `void*` pointer as a "generic type". Not much harm done there, though; just remember that for everyday coding there are more elegant solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think the example is quite bad. One of the canonical examples would be the C library's `qsort`, where you pass in `void*` *as well as* a function which interprets the data.

However, in C++, there are better mechanisms available which are less likely to silently malfunction.

Hence, the use of `void*` to pass generic data around should probably be limited to

1. instances where code bloat is important, and
2. code which interacts with other language, in particular C.

Answer (score 0):

When you are programming C (not C++) void* is you only way to do something generic. Nevertheless the example is terrible. This scheme is often used for callback mechanics, where you pass a function pointer and a void*. For example:

```
void handle_crash(void* data)
{
    Log* log = (Log*)data;
    log->print("We crashed.");
}

Log log;
set_crash_handler(&handle_crash, &log);
```

You will see this often on C frameworks such as libxml2 or spidermonkey. In the case of C this is the only thing there is to accomplish it. It is not a very robust solution.

In case you are working with C++ you have more options. Basic generic programming can be done with templates or overloading as mentioned in other answers. In case you need solid callback mechanic you might want to look into libsigc++ or other "signals and slots" frameworks.